# Intuitive explanation of the Kelly Criterion

Tags: statistics

According to Wikipedia, the optimal fraction of a bankroll to bet is given by expected net winnings of a $1 bet/net winnings if you win. This can be proven using calculus on the expected value of the logarithm of wealth, but I was curious as to whether a more intuitive explanation exists.

Answer (score 1):

Two other issues make the Kelly criterion attractive, in that facing a large number of advantageous bets, I believe it roughly:

- maximises the median of the distribution of your future bankroll
- minimises the expected time until you achieve a target bankroll level

though it can lead to painful volatility in your bankroll and depends on you accurately assessing the advantageousness of bets; both of these can be addressed by so-called "fractional Kelly betting" at the cost of possibly not taking sufficient advantage of profitable opportunities